# Getting XHR pagination working with HAML + Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, haml, kaminari

I am using HAML based templates and pagination seems to be broken for me with Kaminari. I'm sure it's my fault but here's what my template looks like:

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
    $('#events').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@events) %>');
    $('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@events, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
  });

    %ul.activity_list
      #events
        = render :partial => 'event'
```

my _event.html.haml looks like:

```
- @events.each do |event|
  = display_event(event)
```

And finally:

```
  %nav
      %ul.pagination
        #paginator
          = paginate @events, :remote => true
```

What happens now when I load the page is where the paginated events should be I literally see the following markup:

`&lt;%= escape_javascript render(@events) %gt;`

And it renders on the site as:

`<%= escape_javascript render(@events) %>`

What am I doing wrong here to get XHR enabled pagination here?

**UPDATE**

I've updated my javascript to the following as per Dylan's request:

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
    $('#events').html('#{escape_javascript render('event')}');
    $('#paginator').html('#{escape_javascript(paginate(@events, :remote => true).to_s)}');
  });
```

It seems XHR is working, but for some reason, it will never go past page=2. This particular fetch should have 3 pages total and it'll only flip between pages 1 and 2. Any reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use erb tags in a haml file. You should be using haml's version of interpolating ruby code (`#{}` instead of `<%= %>`):

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
    $('#events').html('#{escape_javascript render(@events)}');
    $('#paginator').html('#{escape_javascript(paginate(@events, :remote => true).to_s)}');
  });
```

See the [Haml documentation about this](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_)

Comment: That craps out on - undefined method `model_name' for String:Class. any idea? It appears to be dying on the $('#events') bit.

Comment: And indeed, after I comment out the javascript, everything works minus the XHR bit. (obviously)

Comment: Are you sure `@events` contains your events, and not a string?

Comment: ``@events`` contains an array of strings, it is not a collection of ActiveRecord objects. Maybe I should have made that clear in my question. But yeah, it's just an array of hashes I pulled from Redis that I'm massaging with Kaminari for pagination.

Comment: I believe `render(@events)` expects an array of ActiveRecord objects only. You might just try `render 'event'` to render your `_event` partial, which then iterates over your `@events` array.

Comment: Well, that renders the content. But the XHR portion doesn't work. Makes full page loads, not entirely sure where to take it to next.